# convergent function of $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Define $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$ for every $x\in [a,b]$.

is it true whether a sequence $\{F_n\}$ is convergent to $F$ then $f_n$ is convergent to $f$?

Comment: Do you mean the other way? (i.e. if $f_n \rightarrow f$ then $F_n \rightarrow F$?). I ask because it isn't the case that given arbitrary $F_n$ converging to $F$, that the $F_n$ can be expressed as an integral in the way you define.

Comment: @James. I mean if $f_n =F'_n$ and $f =F'$ then is it true that $f_n\to f$?

Comment: Oh ok, now it is clear. I would imagine that the answer is no, because, as general heuristic, you can't exchange two kinds of limit processes (here taking a derivative, and, taking the pointwise limit) unless you restrict the class of functions. Unfortunately, I can't think of a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: A trivial counterexample: You define $F_n$ via $f_n$, and $F$ via $f$. Let $f_n$ converge to $f$, but change isolated points in $f$. Then, still $F_n\to F$, but $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to $f$ (but still pointwise almost everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the interval $[0,1]$ and define the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ on $[0,1]$ by
\begin{align*}
f_n(x) &= \begin{cases} 1 && \text{if } x\in(0,1] \\ (-1)^n && \text{if } x=0 \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then you have the sequence of function $(F_n)$ on $[0,1]$ where
\begin{align*}
F_n(x)=x.
\end{align*}
The sequence $(F_n)$ converges, but the sequence $(f_n)$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

On $[0,\pi],$ set $f\equiv 0, f_n(x) = \cos nx, n=1,2,\dots $ Then $\int_0^x f_n(t)\,dt = (\sin nx)/n \to 0=f(x)$ uniformly on $[0,\pi].$ But $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ nowhere on $[0,\pi].$